# Binding to a nested Property in DataGrid row tooltip WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, tooltip

I can´t get this working. I have a view) which contains a DataGrid populated with items of an observable collection (MyDataCollection). Every item of MyDataCollection has different properties (Name, Description,..., Logs). Logs is an observable collection itself of Log items. Every Log item has different properties (Date, Person,...).

My data grid populated with items of MyDataCollection has a tooltip per row set. Like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataCollection}">
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <Border>
                                <Grid Margin="5" MaxWidth="400">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                        ...
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    ...
                                    <DataGrid x:Name="LogsGrid" Grid.Row="6" ItemsSource="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext.Logs, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ToolTip}}">
                                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" 
                                                Binding="{Binding Date}" 
                                                />
                                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Person" 
                                                Binding="{Binding Person.FullName}" 
                                                />

                                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                                    </DataGrid>
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        </DataGrid>
```

I can see the tooltip, and I can see the datagrid in the tooltip with the Headers "Date" and "Person" but the grid content is empty. Looks like the binding is not set correct. Can anyone give me a hand? Thanks

*Update 1 :*
MyDataColletion contains objects of my custom class "Car". Here the definition of Car:

```
public class Car : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string name;
    public string description;
    public Contact assignedTo;
    public ObservableCollection<Log> logs = new ObservableCollection<Log>();
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this.name;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.name != value)
            {
                this.name = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }
    }
    public string Description 
    {
        get
        {
            return this.description;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.description != value)
            {
                this.description = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Description");
            }
        }
    }
    public Contact AssignedTo 
    {
        get
        {
            return this.assignedTo;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.assignedTo != value)
            {
                this.assignedTo = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("AssignedTo");
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Log> Logs
    {
        get
        {
            return this.logs;
        }
        private set //TODO : Check if this is correct
        {
            if (this.logs != value)
            {
                this.logs = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Logs");
            }
        }
    }

    public Car()
    {
        // TODO: Delete this: (only here for testing)
        Contact c = new Contact();
        c.Name = "Test";
        c.LastName = "Test";
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
            AddLog(DateTime.Now, c, new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0));
    }
    public void AddLog(DateTime date, Contact person, TimeSpan time)
    {
        Log newLog = new Log(date, person, time);
        Logs.Add(newLog);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

And my Log Class is:

```
public class Log : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    DateTime date; 
    Contact person;
    TimeSpan time;
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get
        {
            return this.date;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.date != value)
            {
                this.date = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Date");
            }
        }
    }
    public Contact Person
    {
        get
        {
            return this.person;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.person != value)
            {
                this.person = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Person");
            }
        }
    }
    public TimeSpan Time
    {
        get
        {
            return this.time;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this.time != value)
            {
                this.time = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Time");
            }
        }
    }

    public Log(DateTime date, Contact person, TimeSpan time)
    {
        this.date = date;
        this.person = person;
        this.time = time;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

Comment: On the ItemsSource binding in the tooltip grid, first remove all the TwoWay/PropertyChanged stuff you put in there. If you read the documentation on those you'll find that they're unrelated. Then add `PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` to that Binding instead, and look in the VS Output pane at runtime. You'll see messages there telling you what happens as it tries to resolve the binding path. You need to find out what actual object the DataContext is for that Binding. That'll tell you.

Comment: I get this error in the VS Output pane: System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'Logs' property not found on 'object' ''DataGrid' (Name='LogsGrid')'. BindingExpression:Path=Logs; DataItem='DataGrid' (Name='LogsGrid'); target element is 'DataGrid' (Name='LogsGrid'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
And then some warnings telling me that the property is null. But this messages are shown when the application is run, not when I add elements to the ObservableCollection. So maybe the items source is not being updated ??

Comment: it's telling you the Logs property does not exist on the Source object. Not empty. Nonexistent -- in the place where it is looking. It's looking in the wrong place. Try `DataContext.Logs` instead.

Comment: This is the Output now: System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=41695345):   At level 0 - for DataGrid.PlacementTarget found accessor <null>
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'PlacementTarget' property not found on 'object' ''DataGrid' (Name='LogsGrid')'. BindingExpression:Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext.Logs; DataItem='DataGrid' (Name='LogsGrid'); target element is 'DataGrid' (Name='LogsGrid'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Comment: Try what I told you. DataContext.Logs. Did you read the trace output and think about it? Do you understand what it is telling you?

Comment: I took your XAML verbatim from your question, removed the "...", and added `<Label Content="{Binding}" Grid.Row="0" />` in the ToolTip. I created a quick viewmodel object with the expected properties, and everything worked as expected. Items appeared in the tooltip grid. You need to share enough code for me to reproduce the issue. What is the class you've got in `MyDataCollection`? It must contain objects of some kind. They are instances of a class. Please share the definition of that class.

Comment: Thanks Ed! I editted the question with the definition of the class in MyDataCollection and the Log class

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly if the DataGrid in the tooltip has its ItemsSource bound like this: `<DataGrid x:Name="LogsGrid" Grid.Row="6" ItemsSource="{Binding Logs}">`. Are you seeing anything in the main grid? Are you putting anything in MyDataCollection?

Comment: The only way I can make it fail is by adding the unnecessary "`Mode=TwoWay`" back to the binding. Then it throws an exception because `Logs` has a private setter, and `Mode=TwoWay` tells the Binding that the `DataGrid` is going to assign a new collection to `Logs` (which isn't true and in fact isn't even possible with any control's `ItemsSource`). But nobody can assign anything to `Logs` because the setter is private, so the binding throws an exception. `Mode=TwoWay` serves no imaginable purpose in this context and must not be there.

Comment: Thanks Ed!! That was it. Do you want to answer this question on an Answer insted of on a comment so I can mark your answer as correct? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I can find in your code that doesn't work perfectly for me is `Mode=TwoWay` in the binding on `LogsGrid.ItemsSource`. That throws an exception for me, because it's telling the `Binding` that you want `LogsGrid` to write new values for `ItemsSource` back to the `Binding` source -- in this case, to the viewmodel's `Logs` property. Not only is that not what you want, but it's actually impossible since `Logs` has a private setter (and furthermore, `DataGrid` doesn't do that anyway). Hence the exception.

`UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` is another one that serves no purpose, though harmlessly this time: That tells it *when* to write new `Logs` collections back to `Car.Logs`. But again, `DataGrid` can't do that. It doesn't create new values for the property. A `TextBox` will assign new `Text` values to the source property, that's what a `TextBox` is for. But `DataGrid` doesn't do that.

When I get rid of those two things, it works fine for me:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="LogsGrid" Grid.Row="6" ItemsSource="{Binding Logs}">
    <!-- etc. -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ItemsSource="{Binding Logs, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">` , use this : `ItemsSource="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext.Logs, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ToolTip}}">`.

Comment: @chincheta73 sorry for slip, plz see my updated answer

Comment: still nothing. The Output pane says this:  System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=41695345): At level 0 - for DataGrid.PlacementTarget found accessor <null> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'PlacementTarget' property not found on 'object' ''DataGrid' (Name='LogsGrid')'. BindingExpression:Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext.Logs; DataItem='DataGrid' (Name='LogsGrid'); target element is 'DataGrid' (Name='LogsGrid'); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

Comment: @chincheta73 I am extremely sorry yet again, forgot to change `RelativeSource`, plz see updated answer yet again.